# binding.pry で「今見ているメソッド」を編集したい

Tags: ruby, pry

binding.pry で、 pry 実行している最中に、今見ているメソッド( `whereami` で表示されるコード断片が定義されているメソッド ) を edit したくなりました。

pry 自体がこの情報を持っているはずなので、どうにかすればこれができるはずだと思っているのですが、現状この方法がわからず、今は

1. `whereami` などでソース表示
2. 今実行しているメソッド名称を端末的にコピー・ペースト

しています。これは、少し手間です。

#### 質問

- binding.pry 実行中に、今いるメソッド(whereami で表示されるメソッド) を、特にそのメソッド名称を打ち込むことなく、 edit することはできますか？

#### 試してみたこと

- `edit` => 何かほとんど空っぽの一時ファイルがひらかれる。(最後の expression だけが書いてある様子。。？)
- `edit __method__` => `NoMethodError: undefined method`first' for nil:NilClass` などが表示され、たぶん何か違うんだろうな、と思っている。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今いる行(whereami)ならば`edit -c`で編集できます．
今いるメソッドの先頭ならば`edit -m`です．

詳しくは`help edit`および、[wiki](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration#wiki-Edit_command)で